# Display user data in ASP.NET core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

Trying to display authenticated user data in an MVC view.
Using ASP.NET Core 2.1

The following error occours:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>       NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>       AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml, line 6

There seems to be a problem with using `@Model.id`. What is the correct way of accessing properties of an authenticated user from within the view?

**Models/LoginModel.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [UIHint("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [UIHint("password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Views/Account/Login.cshtml**

```
@model LoginModel

<h1>Login</h1>

<div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@ViewBag.returnUrl" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password"></label>
        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**Controllers/AccountController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel details, string returnUrl)
{
    ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(details.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result =
                    await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
                        user, details.Password, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl ?? "/");
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(LoginModel.Email),
            "Invalid user or password");
    }
    return View(details);
}
```

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@model ApplicationUser
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Model.Id
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If the user logs in successfully, you are **redirecting** them.  If the controller action that fires because of this doesn't pass a model to the view, then `@Model` will be `null`.

Comment: You didn't show your `HomeController` `Index()` method, but your exception is clear: you didn't pass *any* model to your view. Please understand that you are trying to do completely different things: accessing your model and the logged in user. In ASP.NET Core MVC you may always access your user properties using the claims inside `User` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the `UserManager` into the view, and achieve the same result without having the pass a model into the view:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

And then doing:

```
@await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(User)
```